# advanced LaTeX course

Tags: macros, packages, package-writing, tutorials

I am looking for some tutorial or video-class or something like that about LaTeX advanced course. I want to know more about macros and the creation of packages.

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: The best way is too learn from our gurus (or better idols) here, i.e. the fellows with > 100k reputation ;-)